# Changing the JSON key and keeping its index same

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to change the key of JSON attribute and keep/persist its position/Index.

E.g.

```
{"Test1" : { 
             mytest1:34,
             mytest2:56,
             mytest6:58,
             mytest5:89,
           }
}
```

Now I want to change the key **mytest6** to **mytest4** and keep its position as it is.

**Note:** In my case I can't use Array.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to do it and could you share some code? It's not clear to me where your are stuck...

Comment: "keep its position as it is.". Order of JavaScipt objects' properties is undefined. You can't. If order is a key use an array. Also that **is not** JSON. That's an object, a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    jsonObj = {"Test1" : { 
             mytest1:34,
             mytest2:56,
             mytest6:58,
             mytest5:89,
           }
};

var old_key = "mytest6";
var new_key = "mytest4";

if (old_key !== new_key) {
    Object.defineProperty(jsonObj.Test1, new_key,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(jsonObj.Test1, old_key));
    delete jsonObj.Test1[old_key];
}

console.log(jsonObj);
```

This method ensures that the renamed property behaves identically to the original one.

Also, it seems to me that the possibility to wrap this into a function/method and put it into Object.prototype is irrelevant regarding your question.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/rbvhmttj/)